# Class not getting unloaded while exiting the application(Web start)?

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader, java-web-start

I am working in a client-server application(web start) which is started by url http:\[ip of server]:[port]. It loads index.html in the browser and main application pops up in another window and here we have several option to see/perform status/action.

Recently i got an issue of server status being displayed as unknown which is default, but it after loading application it should be loaded. I found the cause of it, that method to display server status being executed at start, so i use while loop to check if application loads, then i executed that method. It worked.

But if i exit the pop up(main application) and refresh the url in main browser window, application pops up successfully but without server status, There is nothing about server status. It leads me to think that while  cut the pop up, serverStatus class did not unload.

I tried to learn about class loader but did not get anything and not able to find anything in application source code about loading/unloading of a class.

Could someone please guide or give reference to a study materiel that could solve my problem.

Please pardon me if i am not clear in asking the exact question and please ask if more information is required. Thanks in Advance

The changed code is here:

```
@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

synchronized(this){
while(!notCompleted){
Thraed.sleep(100)}
out.println("<LABEL><B>" + discoveryStatusLabel_ +
                        "&nbsp;:</B></LABEL>&nbsp;<SPAN ID='DiscoveryStatus'>" +
                        discoveryStatus_ + "</SPAN>");}
}
```

where i added the while loop, and notCompleted is variable to check if application loaded fully.
Note: There are more code in `doGet()` and `synchronized block` apart from this.

Comment: your runtime didn't end so there is actually no guarantee that a class is unloaded by the GC - even if you invoke `System.gc()` (although the SUN JRE GC does collect here). Furthermore, a class (and its classloader) are only eligible for garbage collection if no strong reference is pointing to classes loaded by that classloader - so if you have singletons or enums chances are high they will prevent the unloading of the classes they are referencing (as well as themselves) and the classloader(s) which load those classes.

Comment: @RomanVottner Yes that is the case actually, as i can see java console still opening and it shows significant amount of memory consumption even the main application exits but main browser still loaded with index.html. If i exit main browser window also then problem solved as application starts as new one and with proper server status.and Moreover i can see many enum used in code as well as static. So shall i consider it no problem?

Comment: The browser itself is not the problem as it only stores a "static" page which might contain scripts to interact "dynamically" with your server or application. You should clarify what you mean by `even the main application exits` - so the java-process has finished? To detect memory leaks use a profile like VisualVM, JProfiler or Eclipse Memory Analyzer and create heapdumps at different "steps" and compare them with each other.

Comment: Next, your code snippet does not show anything useful in my opinion. Your sleep-method is CPU-time-wasting - use `wait()` and `notify()` or better one of the locking mechanisms offered by Java and we don't know either how your variables are defined nor where those values came from.